# Como converter variável int para string sem eliminar os zeros?

Tags: python, python-3.x, conversão-de-tipo

Preciso realizar em uma atividade a validação dos caracteres digitados pelo usuário.

Meu código:

```
mes1 = int (input ('Digite o mês inicial:'))
valida = len (str (mes1))
while valida != 2:
    print ('Valor inválido! O mês deve ter 2 dígitos.')
    mes1 = int (input ('Digite o mês inicial:'))
    valida = len (str (mes1))
```

O problema é que quando converto int para *string* na variável ''valida'', os zeros são desconsiderados. Ex: Digito mês 12, tudo correto; Digito mês 02, erro.

Imagem do erro:

[image: erro com os zeros sendo desconsiderados]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Um valor inteiro não possui zeros a esquerda; se você precisa mantê-los deve manter seu valor como *string*, mas se a intenção é fazer isso para validar um mês, não o faça. O mês 02 é o mesmo que mês 2, então validar se possui dois caracteres não é uma validação suficiente (42 é um mês válido? Tem dois caracteres).

Se você deseja validar se foi digitado um número e se ele é um mês válido você precisará tratar a exceção `ValueError` que é lançada por `int` quando o valor não for numérico e para saber se é um valor válido para o mês basta verificar se está entre 1 e 12 inclusives. Teoricamente se eu informar o "mês 2" ou "mês 02" deveria ser a mesma coisa, então não pode validar se há dois caracteres.

```py
while True:
  try:
    month = int(input('Mês: '))
    if 1 <= month <= 12:
      break
    print('Informe um valor entre 1 e 12')
  except ValueError:
    print('Informe um valor numérico')
```

Ao executar você teria uma saída como:

```
>>> Mês: a
Informe um valor numérico
>>> Mês: 13
>>> Informe um valor entre 1 e 12
Mês: 5
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/GrownFewTrapezoid)</sup>

**Nota importante:** Uma *string* com zero a esquerda é completamente diferente de um valor com zero a esquerda. No Python 2 o zero a esquerda em um número inteiro era utilizado para indicar que o valor era octal, isto é, base 8 e não base 10. Fazer, por exemplo, `print(010)` no Python 2 exibirá 8, pois o número 010 na base 8 equivale ao número 8 na base 10. No Python 3 essa notação foi alterada para `0o10`, com a letra `o` entre os valores e passou a gerar um erro de sintaxe para inteiros com 0 a esquerda. Tome muito cuidado para não confundir as coisas.

Answer (score 3):

É simples, não converta para inteiro, se você já tem a informação do jeito que deseja, então usa ela direto. Se precisa da conversão, faça depois de validar. No fim fiz a conversão se ainda precisa dela, não sei se precisa mesmo, pode ser um erro conceitual aí.

Aproveitei e retirei a redundância do código, agora o pedido aparece uma vez, respeitando o [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101). melhorei a organização do código.

```
while True:
    mes = input('Digite o mês inicial:')
    if len(mes) == 2:
        break;
    print ('Valor inválido! O mês deve ter 2 dígitos.')
mes1 = int(mes)
print(mes1)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/xr5J0J). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/LengthIntpy). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Typing/ConvertToInt.py).

Comment: É que eu queria ao mesmo tempo garantir que não fosse possível o usuário digitar outro caractere, apenas digitar números.

Answer (score -1):

Cara não existe número inteiro com 0 do lado esquerdo 01 == 1 , logo lê o input como string e faz comparação de string.

Comment: É que eu queria ao mesmo tempo garantir que não fosse possível o usuário digitar outro caractere, apenas digitar números.